# For a 2KBytes x 8 memory chips, what is the memory space of MARIE (Addresses x Data bits per addresses)?

Tags: memory, cpu-architecture, digital

So I have worked on this problem and the correct answer I have received does not match what I had and I don't understand why.

The question asks:

*"For a 2KBytes x 8 memory chips, what is the memory space of MARIE (Addresses x Data bits per Addresses)?"*

I thought that I would need to take 2KBytes (or **2^11**) and multiply it by 8 (or **2^13**) to get my answer. But the answer says it's 4K x 16 (or rather **2^12** x **2^4**)

This is review for my exam by the way, and the professor didn't write down why that was the answer. I'm hoping someone might shed some light on this answer and help me understand.

Comment: Why do you think 2^11 * 2^3 is  2^13? Anyway, you didn't say what MARIE is, so this question is hard to answer

Comment: @Leeor MARIE is a computer architecture. And yeah the question is vague for me too.

Answer (score 0):

The question is vague.

But from my understanding, it's asking for the *actual* memory space of the MARIE computer architecture. Each memory of MARIE has instructions of 16 bits, which is made up of an opcode of 4 bits and a single address of 12 bits. Your **2^4** or **16 bits** is the MARIE memory and that's where the correct answer comes from.

The 4K (**2^12**) is the total number of addresses that that MARIE architecture can support.

The question basically ignores the "*For a 2KBytes x 8 memory chips...*" part and is just asking you for the MARIE memory space, which should be the same regardless of what that problem is asking.

I recommend you read up on MARIE to fully understand this.

http://hwmath.com/dev/MarieSim/Marie-Instruction-Set-Cheat-Sheet.pdf